# Remove app (and associated database tables) in Django 1.7

Tags: python, django, django-1.7

Is it possible to use Django 1.7 migrations to completely remove/uninstall an app and all its traces (mainly, all its database tables)?

If not, what is the appropriate way of doing this in Django 1.7?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
python manage.py migrate <app> zero
```

Comment: Thanks, working perfect! Weird I couldn't find this in the official documentation.

Comment: Docs for migrationname "zero": https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#migrate

Comment: That worked in django 3.1 in case any body is wondering

Comment: This does not work if you've messed up some stuff and really want to clear the tables of an app and start from zero.